# How to move selected text vertically with keyboard in VS Code

Tags: visual-studio-code, keyboard-shortcuts

I can move a whole line up or down with <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>up</kbd> and <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>down</kbd>, respectively. I can move selected text left or right with `Move Caret Left` or `Move Caret Right`, respectively (which are unbound by default, at least on the Mac). Is there a way to move selected text (*not* a whole line) up or down, using the keyboard?

Comment: Hang on - I'm close to a solution.  Tomorrow.

Answer (score 2):

Here is as best as I good get - you'll need to write an extension I think to improve on it - but it might work for you.  Using a macro extension like [multi-command](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ryuta46.multi-command)

Settings.json:

```
"multiCommand.commands": [
  {
    "command": "multiCommand.moveCopyUp",
    "sequence": [
      "undo",
      "cursorUp",
      "editor.action.clipboardPasteAction",
    ]
  },
  {
    "command": "multiCommand.copyAndMoveSelectionUp",
    "sequence": [
      "editor.action.clipboardCutAction",        
      "cursorUp",
      "editor.action.clipboardPasteAction",
    ]
  },
  {
    "command": "multiCommand.copyAndMoveSelectionDown",
    "sequence": [
      "editor.action.clipboardCutAction",        
      "cursorWordStartLeftSelect",        
      "cursorDown",
      "editor.action.clipboardPasteAction",
    ]
  },
  {
    "command": "multiCommand.moveCopyDown",
    "sequence": [
      "undo",
      "cursorWordStartLeftSelect",        
      "cursorDown",
      "editor.action.clipboardPasteAction",
    ]
  }
]
```

And keybindings.json:

```
 {
  "key": "alt+u",
  "command": "multiCommand.moveCopyUp",
  "when": "!editorHasSelection && textInputFocus && !editorReadOnly"
},

{
  "key": "alt+u",
  "command": "multiCommand.copyAndMoveSelectionUp",
  "when": "editorHasSelection && textInputFocus && !editorReadOnly"
},

{
  "key": "alt+d",
  "command": "multiCommand.copyAndMoveSelectionDown",
  "when": "editorHasSelection && textInputFocus && !editorReadOnly"
},

{
  "key": "alt+d",
  "command": "multiCommand.moveCopyDown",
  "when": "!editorHasSelection && textInputFocus && !editorReadOnly"
},
```

or whatever keybindings you chose.  This presumes you want to cut the selection you want to move (if not let me know and I may be able to modify this to suit leaving the initial instance of selected text where it was).

This does require that you have an actual selection before invoking a move up/down command.  And that text will be cut to the clipboard and ultimately pasted into the line up/down.  The moved text will move strictly straight up/down, not going to the next end of word for instance - although that could be added I think.

This will work with the move caret left/right commands **if those are done first**.  Otherwise the selected range is lost when it is pasted - it could be stored in an extension though.  Here is a demo (the demo gif unfortunately shows a line being skipped - it doesn't do that in reality) :

[image: demo of moving selections]

Comment: It would be supernice if 'editor.action.clipboardPasteAction' would stay selected, then it's the same as the horizontal moving of selection. Good work anyway!